# Laravel UpdateOR Create not work with relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I want to update my related table on laravel 5.4

my code

```
$id = $request->id;

$find = Presal::find($id);
$find->user_id = $request->customer_id;
$find->proposalid = $request->proposalid;
$psal = $find->save();

if ($psal) {
    foreach ($request->service_item_id as $key => $n) {
        $find->proposalService()->updateOrCreate([
            'service_item_id' => $request->service_item_id[$key],
            'start_date'      => $request->start_date[$key],
            'end_date'        => $request->end_date[$key],
            'service_type_id' => $request->service_type_id[$key],
            'vendor_submit'   => $request->vendor_submit[$key],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here always my code create  a new row in proposalService but not update.
How can I make create if new and Update if exist.

Comment: What is your composite key to update? I mean all attributes those you used here?

Answer (score 0):

`updateOrCreate()` takes 2 arguments (2 arrays). First array, you pass the element you want to check, usually the primary key and some other element. It then checks if those elements exist, else, create a new one.

```
$find->proposalService()->updateOrCreate(
    [
        'service_item_id' => $request->service_item_id[$key],
        'service_type_id' => $request->service_type_id[$key]
    ],
    [
        'start_date' => $request->start_date[$key],
        'end_date' => $request->end_date[$key],
        'vendor_submit' => $request->vendor_submit[$key]
    ]
);
```

Here I used `service_item_id` and `service_type_id` as first argument to check if they already exist.